# How to add transition to drop down list and make font awesome carat rotate on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've gotten my drop down working fine, however on click I would like to add a transition but I read that transitions cannot be added to display properties

Secondly, I would like to rotate the font awesome carat -180deg upon clicking my dropdown list

This is what I have got so far:

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');
const options = document.querySelector('.options');
const rotate = document.querySelector('.fas fa-angle-down');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  options.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.options {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.options li {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 350ms ease;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.rotate-carat {
  transform: rotate(-180px);
}

.options.active li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 350ms all;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
    <span>Company Profile</span>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down" style="float: right;"></i>
  </a>
</li>
<ul class="options">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
<li>
```

Comment: [Kevin Powell - Animate from display none](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4prVdA7_6u0)

Comment: What kind of transition would you like?

Comment: Any of the normal transitions that come with CSS, ease, ease-in, ease-out, etc

Comment: your html is invalid, your options ul should be inside the li

Comment: @Pete that is very incorrect. `ul` stands for 'unordered list' and `li` stands for 'list item'

Comment: check my answer please! I edited this just now!

Comment: @Pete Oh, wait, i think i see what you mean. I apologize for reacting to quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would fix your html - your options `ul` should be inside the `li`

Then I would toggle the class on the clicked button and change your css to use the adjacent child selector.

For the options transition, I would change it from using display to using opacity, this way you can hide your `ul` using height and then transition the opacity of the `li` once your change the height back to auto

For the rotation, you need to use `deg` instead of `px`

I have commented the code below

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) { // pass the event into the function
  // toggle the class on the clicked button
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.options {
  display: block;
  height: 0;               /* height 0 to start off hidden */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.options li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;  /* transition opacity instead of display */
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

/* add a rotation to your icon  */
.fa-angle-down {
  transition: transform 350ms ease;
}

.active .fa-angle-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);  /* use deg instead of px */
}

/* change your active options selector to use the adjacent sibling selector */
.active+.options {
  height: auto;    /* this will show the list before the opacity transitions */
}

.active+.options li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
      <span>Company Profile</span>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down" style="float: right;">test</i>
    </a>
    <!-- fix your html and move your options ul here -->
    <ul class="options">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow this is a great answer, thanks. Seems I was doing extra work in my JS just cause of badly placed HTML, and you one liner-ed it. The rotating carat also works well, thanks a lot man :D

Answer (score 0):

check this out!

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');
const options = document.querySelector('.options');
const rotate = document.querySelector('.rotate-carat');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  options.classList.toggle('active');
  rotate.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.options {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transition: 350ms all linear;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  /*height: 0;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: top;
}

.options li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.rotate-carat {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.rotate-carat.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.options.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  /*height: 10rem;*/
  /*animation: 1s height 350ms forwards;*/
}

@keyframe height {
  from {
    height: 10rem;
  } to {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
    <span>Company Profile</span>
    <span class="rotate-carat">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
<ul class="options">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
<li>
```

Comment: Good effort to be honest, but I'm guessing there will be an empty space below due to the height being 10rem, so the dropdown is just sort of hidden. On a dropdown list like a sidenav there will just be an empty space below

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to add a nice transition that you see on many websites is to use `translateX()`.

So, the menu is displayed, but outside the viewport, so you don't see it. And when it is toggled, it slides in and out.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const toggle = document.querySelector('#menu-toggle');

toggle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    list.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
ul{
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: transform .3s;
}

ul.active{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<button id='menu-toggle'>Show Menu</button>
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Else, i'd recommend watching this video: [Kevin Powell - Animating from display none](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4prVdA7_6u0).